# Set Focus/highlight on a node manually

Tags: javascript, jquery, tree, jstree

I have a jstree that has several nodes with children and some with none

I "**dblclick**" to open the node to display children if any. The "**dblclick**" also changes the URL with the node_ID reflected in it

The above works fine

I "**click**" to select a node... it does nothing, if just sets **focus/highlight** on the selected node as intended, this is fine.

The Problem: On page ***Refresh/Reload*** I want the the **Focus/highlight** to be set on the node_ID reflected on the URL, but it instead it sets focus to the node_id of the last saved state. (the one I **click** on)

I tried

```
$('#jstree').on('ready.jstree', function () {
    alert('ready');
    $('#jstree').jstree('select_node', 'xxx26');
});
```

But this did not work

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6M2Is.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the state plugin (I assume) try binding to the `state_ready.jstree` event instead of the `ready.jstree` event. I believe then your code will work. Just make sure you use the latest jsTree, as `state_ready` was added only recently.

```
$('#jstree').on('state_ready.jstree', function () {
    alert('ready');
    $('#jstree').jstree('select_node', 'xxx26');
});
```